# How to display date in grails which we got from running SQL statement using groovy?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am getting an exception when I try to format the date which is in `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP`. How can format this?

When I try to retrieve the date from the database, I am using the groovy to get the data:

[Groovy doc but it doesn't have anything particular to date](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#DATE)

```
     // Part of the code 
      SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS")
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        sql.eachRow('''select dateCreated from User'''){
           row->
           def dateCreated
           if(row.dateCreated != null){ // I am getting the object as oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP.
            dateCreated= df.format(row.dateCreated)
           }
        }
```

I am getting the exception like this .

> 2015-11-05 14:22:33,755 [http-8083-3] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /getUsers - parameters: _dc: 1446713474579
>
> Stacktrace follows:
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
>   at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:281)
>   at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:140)
>   at java_text_Format$format.call(Unknown Source)
>   at com.test.AdminController$_closure15_closure80.doCall(AdminController.groovy:953)
>   at $Proxy76.eachRow(Unknown Source)
>   at com.test.AdminController$_closure15.doCall(AdminController.groovy:941)
>   at com.test.AdminController$_closure15.doCall(AdminController.groovy)
>   at com.test.SecureController.invokeMethod(SecureController.groovy)
>   at com.test.AdminController$_closure21.doCall(AdminController.groovy:1061)
>   at com.test.AdminController$_closure21.doCall(AdminController.groovy)
>   at org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter.doFilterInternal(JaxrsFilter.java:46)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP` you are talking about, take a look here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMP.html

This class has a lot of usefull methods to convert it to `java.sql.Date` ([dateValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMP.html#dateValue__)) or `java.sql.Timestamp` ([timestampValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMP.html#timestampValue__)) etc.

Once you get to those it's pretty easy to convert them to `java.util.Date`. For example take a loo here [How to convert from java.sql.Timestamp to java.util.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621451/how-to-convert-from-java-sql-timestamp-to-java-util-date)

Answer (score 1):

Cannot format given Object as a Date , this error clearly indicates that first you need to typecast the result you are getting to date and then format it.

```
Date date = Date.parse("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss",row.dateCreated)
```

This should work.