# Display date time in readable format

Tags: java, android, datetime-format

I receive DATETIME from mysql database in a format like this 2016-10-12 18:52:00. Is there an easy way to print it in a readable like 12 October 2016 6:52 pm in java or android?

Comment: Have a look around theres plenty of similar questions on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621451/how-to-convert-from-java-sql-timestamp-to-java-util-date.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do things like:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String S = simpleDate.format(date);  //This will give you like 11/20/2016 08:45:02
```

Now use this form and get the month name programatically according to your need.