# Convert java.sql.Timestamp to java.util.Calendar ISO 8601 format

Tags: java, timestamp, amazon-dynamodb

I have to store updated time in `dynamodb`, while going through the document of `dynamodb` found out we can build an index if we store it in the format of ISO 8601. But in application I have `java.sql.timestamp`. How can I convert it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert from java.sql.Timestamp to java.util.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621451/how-to-convert-from-java-sql-timestamp-to-java-util-date)

Comment: Dates and Timestamps do not have any intrinsic formatting.  Consider using java8 classes or SimpleDateFormat

Comment: @ScaryWombat This is more of a DynamoDB question from what I can tell.  But even there, dates also probably have no intrinsic formatting.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim, yes you are correct.  Maybe it is not even valid to the question and should be marked as a dupe as indicated by vinS.  I did not read the Q proeprly.

Comment: I'd be shocked if the DynanoDB driver for Java can't automatically marshall a timestamp.

Comment: Why have you got a `java.sql.Timestamp` object? The class (along with `Calendar`, `Date` and their friends) is long outmoded. If you can, I recommend you use `java.time.Instant` instead. `java.time` is the modern Java date and time API, it is a lot nicer to work with than the old classes.

Comment: Working with some legacy code and changing it would require me to changing it else where also

Answer (score 8):

**java.time**

First answer, don’t use `java.sql.Timestamp`. This class is long outmoded. Get an `Instant` instead. `Instant` is one of the classes in `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API also known as JSR 310. This API is so much nicer to work with than the old classes. Assuming `inst` is your `Instant`:

```
    String iso8601String = inst.toString();
    System.out.println(iso8601String);
```

On my computer this just printed

```
2017-12-13T11:04:59.282Z
```

The `toString` methods of the modern classes produce ISO 8601 format, which makes your task very easy.

**Convert your Timestamp**

Since (as I understand) you get your `Timestamp` object from legacy code that you cannot afford to upgrade just now: The first thing to do is to convert it to an `Instant`. Then you may proceed as above.

I assume that `ts` is your timestamp. If you are using Java 8 or later:

```
    String iso8601String = ts.toInstant().toString();
```

If you are using Java 6 or 7, you will need to get the ThreeTen Backport (link below). This is the backport of JSR 310 to the mentioned Java versions. Since in these versions, the conversion method isn’t built into the `Timestamp` class, the conversion happens a little differently, everything else is the same. I have not tested the following code line, so please bear with any typo.

```
    String iso8601String = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(ts).toString();
```

**Links**

- [ThreeTen Backport homepage](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)
- [Oracle tutorial trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)

Answer (score 4):

You can call `.toInstant().toString()` on the `java.sql.timestamp` to get an ISO-8601 time string.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you necessarily have to do any heavy manual lifting here, as I would expect a good driver to be able to handle this.  Assuming you do need a manual conversion from `java.sql.timestamp` to an ISO 8601 compliant string, you could try the following:

```
public String getISOTimestamp(java.sql.timestamp ts) {
    Date date = new Date(ts.getTime());
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    String isoTS = sdf.format(date);

    return isoTS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

DyanmoDB itself is schemaless (you dont define non-key attribute types up front) and it [and does not recognise date as a type.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes). You can use a String in Dynamo to store dates

> You can use the string data type to represent a date or a time stamp.
>   One way to do this is by using ISO 8601 strings, as shown in these
>   examples:
>
> 2016-02-15
>
> 2015-12-21T17:42:34Z
>
> 20150311T122706Z

If you are using an object modelling library, like [DynamoDBMapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html), it will do some type marshalling on your behalf. For example [DynamoDBMapper handles many Java data types including](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html)

> This section describes the supported primitive Java data types, collections, and arbitrary data types.
>
> DynamoDB supports the following primitive data types and primitive wrapper classes.
>
> String
>
> Boolean, boolean
>
> Byte, byte
>
> Date (as ISO_8601 millisecond-precision string, shifted to UTC)
>
> Calendar (as ISO_8601 millisecond-precision string, shifted to UTC)
>
> Long, long
>
> Integer, int
>
> Double, double
>
> Float, float
>
> BigDecimal
>
> BigInteger

So you can use something like DynamoDBMapper to marshall data between dates in your code and Strings in your database, or you could just do this yourself. In either case the data in DynamoDB is just **Strings**, and your index is ordered as a String. Using ISO 8601 format just means your Strings are ordered naturally.